# Respecting the OP when editing

Tags: discussion, support, edits, rollback-wars

I was editing a question and the OP had two blocks of comments like this:

```
  // notice that I am two spaces in
  int main(void) {
      ...
      return 0;
  }
```

and the second block was like this:

```
int main(void) {
        ...
        return 0;
}
```

So I thought that it would be nice to indent a bit the code (4 spaces as tab and the 1st block to start from the left edge of the post).

I did it, edit was approved by the "bigger" users.

However, the OP edit back only the first block (he left the second as is), but brought the 1st block in the original position. So now, you had the 1st block starting two spaces from the left side of the post and then 2nd, starting from the left side.

Again, I thought that it would be more uniform that the 2 blocks of code share the same format, so I thought about editing...

*But*, the OP had undo some of my edit. Did I do well I edited, or I ""violated"" the rule:

**Respect the OP**.

?

You see I am new at this, so I would like an experienced point of view, so that I know what I should do in the future. I felt a little bad for editing for a 2nd time his post, but I also felt a little bad about future users that would read two blocks of code, which weren't uniform.

And OK, this wasn't a big deal. The question is:

**If the OP removes the edits that one performed (and approved), should we perform the edit again?**

Comment: Look at the timestamp on the edits. It is most likely that the original poster was editing at the same time that you were editing. He  started with the original version. Your updates weren't merged in. His changes just overrode yours.

Comment: @CodyGray, even if that was the case (it was made the same hour, but I **think** it was different), I think the question still holds, since some people may undo the approved edit.

Comment: Well, it is relevant to the answer. If the OP obviously undid your edits by mistake, then you can replace them. If they *disagreed* with your edits and intentionally undid them, then you should leave it alone. Don't get into an edit war. If you feel that the content is hurting the site in its current state, flag it for moderator attention. Explain your problem, point out that your edit was rolled back, and they'll take care of it e.g. by locking the post.

Comment: Yes it is relevant. But how should I know if it was by purpose or by mistake? Ask in a comment, that is not going to be helpful at the future? @CodyGray ( I think that you comment can also play the role of an answer).

Comment: Looking at the timestamp is how I tell, generally. If I feel real strongly about my edit, I'll redo it once. And leave a comment explaining why the OP should leave it put. You leave the edit button alone after that, whatever happens.

Comment: Oh when you said by mistake, you meant that he wasn't aware of my action, since he was doing his edit in parallel. I felt bad that I edited again, so I will agree.